# How do I use the Selection tool to move things in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

Using GIMP 2.6.11

My previous image-editing software of choice was Microsoft Paint, which was very intuitive: make a rectangle, click + drag to move the contents of the rectangle around.

How do I replicate this functionality in GIMP? I seem to only be able to:

- a) move the entire layer around, ignoring the selection entirely, or
- b) move the selection around, without moving anything that's *within* the selection (which is what I'm trying to do).

I have the feeling that I'm missing something extremely basic.

Comment: Gimp is a powerful tool, but I recommend the free Paint.net as a more suitable next step up from Microsoft Paint. Paint.net is much more like a regular Windows program in usage than Gimp.

Comment: @MatthewLock I wouldn't recommend it to beginner. After many years of using paint.net I finally got fed up with all the BS it has, lack of basic features and ignorant narcissistic devs that never listen to suggestions on forums. I moved to GIMP recently and I can't express how much better it is in EVERYTHING. UI/Features/Tools/Workflow/Formats... I would recommend newcomers to start with GIMP and not waste time on an abomination of paint.net.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Once you selected whatever part of the picture you want to move, press `ctrl-x` and then `ctrl-v`. This will cut and paste the selection to a new layer. Now you can use the move tool to move the new layer around.

Note: The move tool can move layers, selections, and paths. Make sure the layer option in the move tool is selected (in the toolbox).

**Edit:**

You can also select an area, then **hold down** `ctrl-alt` and **drag** the selected area as described [here](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-using-selections.html). Once you start dragging, you can release the `ctrl` key to stop constraining the move to cardinal directions. After dropping the selection, you can still move it with the arrow keys.

Rotating and scaling selections seem to behave as expected (automatically creating a new layer). I'm not sure why they didn't make the move tool behave like that too.

Comment: I had discovered this, but it seems like a workaround rather than the primary way to do this. Is this really the only way?

Comment: @Raven Dreamer There are many ways to do it. Unfortunately the most intuitive way doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Damn. I could have *sworn* I tried the ctrl-alt method before only to have it not work. But now it's working perfectly, and doing exactly what I need. Grr, technology, you irritate me sometimes. Thanks!

Comment: @Raven Dreamer, Yeah I was confused with the ctrl-alt trick for a bit myself. It only works with the selection tools. If you are using the move tool, ctrl-alt will just move the selection instead of the selected portion of the image. Glad I could help.

Comment: To me, GIMP is very unintuitive in many ways, and this is one of examples. Thank you for the tip. Your previous comment IS the real answer.

Comment: unreal this is so unintuitive. on mac it is shift+option+command.

Comment: this answer is kinda outdated. see @Paddy Collins 'S answer working perfectly on Linux gimp 2.8

Comment: Um... release Ctrl to overcome a restriction of movement, as implied in the edit to the answer, should not be necessary - this restriction does not exist. It is actually something that some users would like to be added as a feature to GIMP, but as of yet it does not exist...

Comment: This is terrible design, it's worse than if they had just blindly copied what every other app does as OP described.

Answer (score 71):

The right way to do this is to use a Floating Selection. The currently accepted answer of doing a Copy/Paste creates a new layer which is undesirable in most cases.

How to make a floating selection:

- Make your selection (e.g. press <kbd>R</kbd> and draw a box).
- Select -> Float (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>)
- Move your Selection (Press <kbd>v</kbd> and then click and drag).
- Anchor Layer <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>

Comment: Worked in GIMP 2.8.

Comment: I like this one, it feels less hacky, (although I'm mainly a programmer, so that stuff bothers me more than it does most)

Comment: This is the proper way to do it. There's no need to mess up your clipboard.

Comment: works and clearly written. But don't seem to need step 3 anymore.

Comment: Basic functionality made so complicated you have to google it. wow.

Comment: Be sure your Move tool is set to "Move layer" mode. Mine was in "Move selection" from prior attempts to get this working.

Answer (score 14):

The following is an updated and simplified answer to this older issue.

There are two tools being discussed: the **Selection Tool** and the **Move Tool**. One might intuitively think you use the selection tool to select, and then hop over to the move tool to move.  That is not the case.

All the work is performed with the **Selection Tool**.  Don't use the Move Tool.

Choosing the **Rectangle Selection Tool**, for example, one selects an area.  While remaining on the selection tool, one uses <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd> to drag the selected image to a different location.  Once having done so, it seems that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd> is no longer needed for further selection movement (as of at least 10/2014, GIMP 2.8.20).

There are also hints provided in the status bar to try combinations of <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>,<kbd>CTRL</kbd>, and <kbd>ALT</kbd>, and indicates what will occur as you press them.

More info here: https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-using-selections.html

Comment: This doesn't work with GIMP 2.8.16 on Windows. It just moves the selection.

Comment: @mitch Just tested and it works for me in 2.8.20.  Before updating to this, make sure Alt isn't getting hooked by Windows and being used by something else (in which case it won't be seen by Gimp).  Also, you might need to press Alt *first*, then Ctrl.  See https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-using-selections.html.

Answer (score 11):

**Note:** *DO NOT select the move tool* after making the selection. Instead, just press and hold <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and start dragging the selection.

---

On **Windows** computers:
After making a rectangular or oval selection, hold <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> to move the contents of the selection.

- If you want to duplicate the contents of the selection, hold <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> instead.

On **Mac** computers, hold down <kbd>option</kbd> and <kbd>command</kbd> and then drag the selection.

- Similarly, if you want to duplicate the contents of the selection, hold <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> instead.

Comment: This doesn't work with GIMP 2.8.16 on Windows. It just moves the selection.

Comment: This worked for me with Gimp 2.10.18 on Windows 10. But when done with the move, how do I make the marquee go away? I tried exporting while the marquee was going, and it worked, but the old selection area was in a light shadow that I had to paint away. It worked but how do I get the marquee to go away and not leave that shadow of the old selected area?

Comment: Best answer. Upvoted!

Answer (score 2):

None of the suggested solutions worked for me.  I eventually realized that the layer I was selecting inside of, was not the same size as the image.  So when I moved my copied selection, it moved outside the layer I was on, and thus displayed as an empty selection.

Making the current layer the same size as the image solved the problem.  After that copy/paste/drag worked as expected.

**To Resize the Layer to Image Size:** <kbd>Alt + L</kbd>, then click on Layer to Image Size

Comment: I was stuck with this problem for so long, while trying to compose a bigger image than the initially imported one. I even think this happened one other time, but I didn't have time to research. To anyone not sure if this is their scenario, note the yellow dashed line, which is the border of the layer, where the moved selection will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, the question was also asking about the selection process. One way to select part of an image for editing is to use the magic selection wand. This works well if there is only one image on the selected layer (this is the way I tend to work so I can edit easily).

Select the layer the image to be moved is on, and use the fuzzy select wand to select what is outside the image (could be a single colour or a transparent background). Once the desired part of the layer has been selected, choose Select/Invert from the menu (this inverts the fuzzy selection from what is outside the part of the image to be moved to what is to be moved), then use ctrl/alt and the mouse to move the selected portion of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + Alt did not work for me.Neither did turning it into a floating selection for whatever reason. I may need to just fiddle with it but I was in a hurry.

**Layers Solution:**
I had to make the selection, <kbd>Ctrl + X</kbd> to cut, <kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd> to paste, then in the layers tab I turned the "pasted floating selection" into a layer. I could then move that new layer around. When you're done you can right click that layer and "Merge Down" if you need it to all be one layer again.